# Using RecyclerView on Newer Android Devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, gradle-dependencies

Is it important to add dependencies for RecyclerView if my app is only going to run on Android Lollipop and newer versions?

A lot of tutorials keep adding these dependencies but I am not sure if they do it to support very old devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

There is no need to include additional dependencies for `RecyclerView`.

### Extended Answer

Since your app is going to run on `Android Lollipop (API Level 21)` and newer versions, it is not necessary to add specific dependencies for `RecyclerView`.
`RecyclerView` is part of the `Android Support Library`, which was included to provide backward compatibility for older versions.

Since `API level 21`, `RecyclerView` was included in the `Android` framework, so you can use it without adding any dependencies in your `gradle` file, now are in the `AndroidX` libraries, so now the `RecyclerView` class is available in `androidx.recyclerview.widget`, which is part of the `AndroidX` libraries.